# Connect PHP pages in dreamweaver to MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

I'm trying to connect a series of five select menus created on Dreamweaver to generate one result through this query below. I keep getting errors every time I run the query. This is the query I have on my PHP page:

```
 enter code here
<?php

$connect= mysql_connect("localhost","root", "password");
// Check connection
if (!mysql_select_db('db_name', $connect)) {
    echo 'Could not select database';
    exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT SER_ID and ser_type FROM services 
INNER JOIN service_type ST
ON s.SER_ID= st.SER_ID
inner join profile P
on st.P_ID = p.P_ID
inner join room_services rs
on rs.SER_ID = s.SER_ID
inner join room r
on r.R_ID = rs.R_ID
inner join room_sensor rse
on rse.R_ID = r.R_ID
inner join sensor sen
on sen.S_ID = rse.S_ID
inner join service_sensor ss
on ss.SER_ID = s.SER_ID
inner join services_conditions sc
on sc.SER_ID = s.SER_ID
inner join conditions c
on c.C_ID = sc.C_ID
where p.username = Adam
AND sen.sensor_type = motion detector";

$result= mysql_query($sql, $connect); 
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ser_ID</th>
<th>service_Type</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_query($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ser_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['service_Type'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['ser_ID'];
    echo $row['serice_Type'];
}

mysql_free_result($result);

mysql_close($connect);
?>
    enter code here

    enter code here
```

The error I keep receiving is:

> DB Error, could not query the database MySQL Error: Query was empty

This is happening despite the fact that the query is running completely fine on phpMyAdmin.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I suspect that the strings "Adam", and "motion detector" require single quotes.

Comment: Consider using `mysql_error` to get the real error instead of your vague error string. Furthermore, please don't use `mysql_` instead, consider using `mysqli_` or `PDO` as `mysql_` is deprecated and even removed in php 5.5 +

Comment: I got the same result using mysqli_ as well. I'm still not sure where the error is coming from!

Comment: Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\site1\services.php on line 7
Could not select database

Comment: So thats the new error coming up after putting 'Adam' and 'Motion detector' in quotes

Comment: Why don't you run it outside your application to make sure it's not an sql problem?